# Importing Latest Modified Excel FIle With Multiple Sheets

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012, ssis-2008, msbi

I have multiple excel files with multiple sheets with same structure, i am getting newest file using script task but not able to load all sheets using for each loop. any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In order to read all the data from different sheets from the excel file using For each loop container you can follow the same procedure as mention in this post: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4157/how-to-read-data-from-multiple-excel-worksheets-with-sql-server-integration-services/
This post however uses the Old DB provider to read across all the sheet and it works. 
Let me know in case you are using a different provider to read the excel.